# How to enumerate a subset of files in Data Lake Store?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-data-lake

I have a large number of files stored in a Data Lake Store - I now need to get the *latest* file.

Because I haven't found a better way, my current approach involves listing all the files and looking at the modified date. However, I suspect that can cause some issues when dealing with a larger set of files. The API has a way of limiting it, by calling the following method:

```
var statuses = _client.FileSystem.ListFileStatus(_store._dlsAccountName, "/the/path", 2);
```

which would only give me 2 files. However, they seem to be returned in alphabetical order.

Does anybody know how to:

- enumerate the latest files only, *or*
- change the way the list file status returns results?

Comment: Is it an option to segment the files by date (e.g. a new directory for each date)?

Comment: @mjwills I don't think that will help -> I would still need to iterate through many dates, as a day may not have a result I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned the function **ListFileStatus** result is not ordered by modification time. I also don't find a function that list lasest files in the [Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store/) SDK.

> change the way the list file status returns results?

Yes, as [FileStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datalake.store.models.filestatusproperties?view=azuremgmtdatalakestore-2.1.0-preview) has [modification time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datalake.store.models.filestatusproperties.modificationtime?view=azuremgmtdatalakestore-2.1.0-preview#Microsoft_Azure_Management_DataLake_Store_Models_FileStatusProperties_ModificationTime) Property, we could list latest files with following code.

```
var number = 2;
var statuses = _client.FileSystem.ListFileStatus(_store._dlsAccountName, "/the/path").FileStatuses.FileStatus.ToList().OrderByDescending(x=>x.ModificationTime).Take(number);
```

I tested it on my side, it works correctly.

Comment: Hey Tom! Thanks for that. I imagine that's oData underneath, and the LINQ code will translate to a REST statement?

Comment: Hi Anže Vodovnik, sorry for reply late. LINQ code doesn't translate to a REST statement, it will list all of the records to client. If it is useful, please mark it.

Comment: Thanks. That means that for a large set of files, enumerating that will be a long-running operation. Ugh... :( Thanks for the info.